# Is it safe to invoke a AJAX call and let the browser cancel the request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, browser

If I make a AJAX reqeust it will be displayed in the network tab in Chrome. If I in the same moment makes a client based redirect, the AJAX request will canceled. But will the request make it to the server and execute as normal? Is it something in HTTP/TCP that know's that the client has canceled the request? I don't think so, but I want to be sure.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where synchronous requests (`async: false` in the `$.ajax(...)` options) are appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Post it as answer @ThiefMaster :)

Comment: There can be a client-based move away from the page at *any* time, I don't see how this merits a special case for a synchronous call. If your code *deliberately* does a redirect after an async request, I'd argue it's the code that's sketchy.

Comment: Just to be clear: if you make the call it _will_ make it to the server. If you have a server set up on your local machine, write a script that takes a while to return, make an ajax call to it and then hit leave the page. Your server _will_ still be processing the request

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, That depends on what you're running server-side.

Comment: @Brad: fair enough... I don't know what is wrong with me today, I'm making all sorts of half-arsed assumptions. So, yes, it depends on what you're running server-side _and_ headers can help you, too (using chunked transfer encoding, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running PHP server-side, it **will** stop processing in the event of a client-side abort. (From what I've read, this isn't the case with other server-side technologies, which will continue processing after a client aborts.) See:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

But, it's best not to assume anything one way or another. The browser **may** cancel the request. And this cancellation **may** occur in time to stop processing server-side. But, that's not necessarily the case. The client could cancel at any stage during the request -- from right before the request is actually sent to just after a response body is sent. Also bear in mind, there are other things which can interrupt server-side request processing (hardware, power, OS failure, etc.). **Expect some unpredictability.**

From this, I'd make two recommendations:

- **Write your code be as transaction-safe as possible.** If a request makes data changes, don't commit them until all changes have been piped to the database. And if your application relies on multiple AJAX requests to change some data, don't commit any of the changes until the the end of "final" AJAX request.
- **Do not assume, even if a request finishes, that the client receives the response.** Off the top of my head, that means if your application is AJAX-heavy, always rely on client-side state to tell the server what information it has, rather than relying on server-side state to assume the client "knows" something.

Comment: If anyone would add to or edit my list of recommendations, please do so!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases where synchronous requests (`async: false` in the `$.ajax(...)` options) are appropriate. This usually avoids the browser from navigating to the other page until the request has finished.